# c++ pointer to abstract class (with parameters) without default constructor

Tags: pointers, abstract-class, default-constructor

i am trying to use a pointer (called `currentState`) of an abstract class called `GameState`, which will then be used to store instances of implementations of said class (for instance, `MainMenuState`, `OverworldState`, `BattleState`, etc).

the `GameState` abstract class' constructor always requires 1 parameter (a window to draw on), so i have no default constructor without parameters. this leads to an error (no appropriate default constructor available).

what's the best practice to solve this problem?

```
/*
 * GameState.hpp
 */
#ifndef GameState_HPP
#define GameState_HPP

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GameLoopObject.hpp"

/// gamestate base class
class GameState : public GameLoopObject {
public:
    GameState(sf::RenderWindow & w); //: GameLoopObject(w) {}; // constructor
    virtual ~GameState(); // destructor

    /*
     * Game Loop functions
     */
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Draw();
    virtual void HandleInput();
    virtual void Reset();
};

#endif //GameState_HPP


/*
 * GameStateManager.hpp
 */
#ifndef GameStateManager_HPP
#define GameStateManager_HPP

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "GameLoopObject.hpp"
#include "GameState.hpp"
#include<string>
#include<map>

class GameStateManager : public GameLoopObject {
private:
    GameState * currentState;
    GameState * nextState;
public:
    std::map<std::string, GameState> gameStates{}; // list where all known gamestates are stored.
    // methods
    GameStateManager(sf::RenderWindow & w);
    void AddGameState(std::string name, GameState * state);
    void SetNext(std::string name);
    void SwitchState();
    void HandleInput(); 
    void Update();
    void Draw();
    void Reset();
};

#endif //GameStateManager_HPP
```

Answer (score 1):

Store pointers instead

```
std::map<std::string, GameState*> gameStates{};
```

Comment: this only leads to more errors. are you sure this should help? i have no problem storing the actual gamestates in the pointers. the problem lies in when the two pointers are created and ask for a default constructor.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't create a container to store instances of classes that don't have a default constructor. You could however create the objects, then store pointers to them, this is very common. The other option is to add a default constructor to the class to be stored.

Comment: storing the actual gamestates works fine. my question is about creating the currentState and nextState pointers. any idea on that? or is there something im missing?

Answer (score 0):

i didnt find an answer for my question, because i think its impossible to do what i was trying to do.

what i ended up doing was deleting the parameter in the abstract class (GameLoopObject and GameState now dont need a window) and implementing the parameter (window) only in the implementation of the class (f.i., MainMenuState(sf::referencewindow &w) )

now i can make the pointers i was trying to make because their constructors are now default anyways.